# Z-Transform of a Precoder with XOR

Tags: z-transform, digital-filters, frequency-response, coding

I am reading a paper called "Design and Comparison of Three 20-Gb/s Backplane
Transceivers for Duobinary, PAM4, and NRZ Data" and got stuck on seemingly easy thing, how the Z-domain representation of the shown precoder is given like that? I am thinking that XOR is not even a linear operator to have a Z-transform for it?

[image: Precoder]

Comment: I agree with you. The question is what they do with that "transfer function". If they just use it to describe the precoding, in analogy with linear filter structures, then no damage is done. However, if they use it to compute a power spectrum then I think you should be careful when interpreting the result.

Comment: But why this form of H(z) exactly? is it because it marks an accumulator and the XOR is like addition?

Comment: I'd say because of the analogy with the difference equation $y[n]=x[n]-y[n-1]$. But I'm also not sure if that description is actually useful.